# Firebase is not working after apk is signed

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I have used FCM to implement push notifications in my application. Now what issue I am facing is that when I run the build from my laptop the fcm runs perfectly and I get notifications. When I create a signed apk and upload on internal test channel in playstore it does not work although I can see the fcm token being updated at the backend where we have saved the token.

I saw in few questions where they as to add SHA-1 key in firebase console but I have already added that while adding the app in firebase. I also checked the app signing key in "Release Management - > App Signing" section in google play console, where it is showing the same SHA-1 key that I added while creating a project. 
Now when i try to add the SHA-1 key in the console it is giving me issue of "Your operation was forbidden.". Help me out to how to make this work.

This is my gradle code :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"

    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo/" }
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xx.xx"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 291
        versionName "2.8.6.9.10"
        generatedDensities = []
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        manifestPlaceholders = [manifestApplicationId          : "${applicationId}",
                                onesignal_app_id               : "xx",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "xx"]
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'src/main/java-gen', 'src/main/Kotlin']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
        }

        beta {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/beta/res']
        }
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    flavorDimensions("main", "beta")
    productFlavors {
        main {
            minSdkVersion 16
            dimension = "main"
        }
        beta {
            minSdkVersion 21
            dimension = "beta"
        }
    }
    aaptOptions {
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
    }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.5.1'
    //    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
    //    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.5.1'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$rootProject.playServicesVersion"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.4'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.3"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4"
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-alpha2'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.picasso:picasso2-okhttp3-downloader:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:4.35.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    implementation 'de.greenrobot:greendao:2.1.0'
    implementation 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    //CirclePageIndicator
    implementation 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.clevertap.android:clevertap-android-sdk:3.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    implementation('com.github.anshulagarwal06:Lumiere:v1') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.firebase'
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'io.smooch:core:5.13.1'
    implementation 'io.smooch:ui:5.13.1'
    implementation 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.2.0'
    implementation 'uk.co.samuelwall:material-tap-target-prompt:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    implementation('com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-mobile-client:2.6.+@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.22'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.6.22'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.1'
    implementation 'nl.dionsegijn:konfetti:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.freshdesk:freshchat-android:1.5.3'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Are you using proguard? Have you added all project flavors to firebase (inhouse, production) and in your app google-services.json? Any static/hardcoded values in your notification implemention?

Comment: how to add flavors in firebase? and no proguard is not enabled.

Comment: can you post your gradle setup?

Comment: @Javatar yes I added the code

Comment: So.. without going through all your code (what build you used, projects added to firebase, messaging implementation, ...) I can't really tell much, sry. Maybe check your build (main/beta/release...) and packagename you uploaded and check if you have added it to firebase (next to your build on your "laptop"). Also it might help to go through Lint.

Comment: it seems that other project has same sha-1 key, which is causing the problem. but I am not able to find which project has that sha key.

Comment: @ParthAnjaria : Did u find issue?